# Stored procedure doing nothing with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, procedure, declare

I have the following stored procedure with postgresql doing no updates whereas the second one below (outside of a stored procedure) is working perfectly. I'm new to stored procedure and struggling to find out why. Any idea?

The one which is not working:

```
DECLARE
  departements TEXT[];
  dept TEXT;
BEGIN
    departements := ARRAY['05','06','07','08'];
FOREACH dept IN ARRAY departements LOOP
raise info '%', dept;
    UPDATE table AS m SET mycolumn = CAST(round(m.valeur * (1 + e.evolution / 100)) AS integer) FROM evolution AS e WHERE m.code_dept = dept AND m.annee = e.annee;
END LOOP;     
END;
```

The one working (but with single value '05' and outside of the stored procedure):

```
UPDATE table AS m SET mycolumn = CAST(round(m.valeur * (1 + e.evolution / 100)) AS integer) FROM evolution AS e WHERE m.code_dept = '05' AND m.annee = e.annee;
```

Thanks a lot in advance!
Sam

Comment: You need to update your question to include the complete procedure text as what you show now is incomplete and incapable of running.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with a stored procedure, unless this is part of a much larger procedure (not shown). As is single `update` statement is all that is needed. Simply replace `m.code_dept = '05'` in your query with `m.code_dept = ANY ARRAY['05','06','07','08'];`

```
update table as m
   set mycolumn = cast(round(m.valeur * (1 + e.evolution / 100)) as integer)
  from evolution as e
 where m.code_dept = any array['05','06','07','08']
   and m.annee = e.annee;
```

**NOTE:** As a rule whenever you create a loop and the body of that loop contains a single statement then that entire loop can be written in a single statement. When working with SQL you need to think in terms of the entire set not individual items.